# Error while uploading catalog product images in magento

Tags: magento

I am having issues while uploading images to catalog product images. while uploading image got back with error "SSL Error: Invalid or self-signed certificate" even site is not set to HTTPS URL.

[image: SSL error while uploading images to product]

But, admin secure url is set to "No" in AdminPanel>>System>>Configuration>>web settings.

How could i resolve this issue?. Please let me know, anyone have find solutions.

Thanks,

Prasanth P

Answer (score 2):

Try the following:

- Temporary disable your Antivirus and most importantly your Firewall.
- Make sure the file you try to upload dose not contain special
  characters.
- Try uploading it from another browser with extensions
  disabled. Or open firefox in safe mode or private browsing. Same if you using chrome or whatever.
- Update your flash player. Or uninstall the old one and install a fresh copy from adobe.com
- Try uploading from another computer

In my case was the firs one. The firewall was blocking the flash player.

Comment: You saved my day, in my case was the first one too.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the following line to your php.ini file:

```
suhosin.session.cryptua = off
```

HTH

Comment: i don't think, it is useful!!. I tried rename the image and upload. Its work. But don't know, what it is behind worked!!...